# Having a DataTable as a cell value of another DataTable in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

so my problem is that I want to display a table inside another table in WPF.

I use a `DataTable` in order to display some data and there is one column, in which I need to display another `DataTable`. I set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`. For a little testing, this is what I wrote (well, it works as expected):

```
  var curDataTable = new DataTable();
  curDataTable.Columns.Add("name"  , typeof(string));
  curDataTable.Columns.Add("number", typeof(int));

  DataRow curRowData = curDataTable.NewRow();
  curRowData[0] = "jones";
  curRowData[1] = 90;
  curDataTable.Rows.Add(curRowData);
```

Now, let's say I already have a filled `DataTable` _dataTable. I now want to display this _dataTable in my second column. This is what i would expect to work, but what does not work:

```
  var curDataTable = new DataTable();
  curDataTable.Columns.Add("name" , typeof(string));
  curDataTable.Columns.Add("table", typeof(DataTable));

  DataRow curRowData = curDataTable.NewRow();
  curRowData[0] = "jones";
  curRowData[1] = _dataTable;
  curDataTable.Rows.Add(curRowData);
```

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: You cannot do this with a `DataTable`. Replace the `DataTable` with a custom class with properties.

Comment: the problem is, that I do neither know the size of my outer `DataTable`, nor the size of my inner `DataTable` .... do you think it would work with a custom class that has one property which is a `ObservableList` ?

Comment: Yes, or an array or something like that. It won't work with a nested `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Using nested `DataTables` won't work.

What you should do is to replace the outer `DataTable` with a custom type and bind to a custom collection property of this type in a `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that nested DataTables are possible...
What you can do is create new column in '_datatable' with the name of "name"

```
_datatable.Columns.Add("name" , typeof(string)).SetOrdinal(0);
```

Using `SetOrdinal(0)` you can make "name" column first column. Now you maybe able to add new columns to it.

I hope it helps

Comment: Well, hopefully understanding your answer, this would be an option if "name" was the only column in the outer DataGrid. Since there are more columns, this will not help me unfortunately